# Dropdown toggle not working properly

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery for dropdown toggle. It works fine only at the time of starting.

What I want to do is, my dropdown menu should disappear when clicking on any place inside body of the page.

I have applied below jQuery. But it is working only once. If again I click the dropdown means the dropdown menu is not showing....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
        </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would not do this by jQuery. This is easy done with CSS only. See below link. This code could be made so it would fit your need.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972655/pure-css-several-read-more-read-less

Comment: Also use the ID-attribute for scripts and the class-attribute for CSS only :)

Comment: Hey mplungjan
Your code is perfectly fine just remove $(this).find
so instead of 

$(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
it will be

$(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example. I am using slow instead of fast to make it more prominent

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".btn-primary").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdown Example</h2>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data- toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About 
       Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet

*change method **find** to **next** that's only.*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
  }
});
</script>
<button class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
        </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It rolls up as it has done its animation with rolling down.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this by another approach -  by CSS. By this way you are sure it would always run. I have edited an earlier answer/question to your needs. You might edit it further so it will fits your needs.

```css
.wrapper-state {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper-target {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 2s ease;
-webkit-transition: width 2s;
}

.wrapper-state~.wrapper-wrap {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper-state:checked~.wrapper-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper-state:checked~.wrapper-wrap .wrapper-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.wrapper-state~.wrapper-trigger:before {
  content: 'Products \9662;';
}

.wrapper-state:checked~.wrapper-trigger:before {
  content: 'Products \9662;';
}

    .wrap-target ul li {
      display: none;
    }

    .wrap-state:checked~.wrapper-wrap ul li {
      display: block;
    }

.wrapper-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  background-color: #2E181A;
  color: #E6D9BD;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-trigger:hover {
  border: 1px solid #2E181A;
  background-color: #E6D9BD;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #2E181A;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="wrapper-state" id="post-wrap" />
   
<label for="post-wrap" class="wrapper-trigger"></label>

<div class="wrapper-wrap">
  <span class="wrapper-target">
    <div class="wrapper-target">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </span>
</div>
```