# How to add and remove class from next parent li element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add/remove class as per li element using Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
<li class="dropdown mega-drop pstatic"><a href="#" class="mainmenuitem">Programs <span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-h-drop-menu fwidth activeul">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Business</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
                <li><a href="#">Business Office Administration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="pstatic"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Health Care &amp; Administration </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-v-drop-menu w-100">
                <div class="row fullmenu">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Health Services Administation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Limited Scope X-Ray Technician </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Medical Front Office And Billing </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Dental Assistant </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Medical Assistant Technician </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Patient Care Technician</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">HVAC</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
                <li><a href="#">Heating, Ventilation, and Air Conditioning</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Information Technology</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
                <li><a href="#">Computer And Network Technician</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Information Technology</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Nursing</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
                <li><a href="#">Nursing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Cosmetology</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu s-drop">
                <li><a href="#">Cosmetology</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown mega-drop"><a href="#" class="mainmenuitem">mega  <span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-h-drop-menu activeul firststepmegamenu">
        <div class="megacontainer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2five">
                    <div class="title first">
                        <p>Los Angeles</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Jacksonville</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orlando</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Houston </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2five">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>San Diego</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Jacksonville</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orlando</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Houston </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2five">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>Bakersfeild</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Jacksonville</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orlando</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Houston </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2five">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>Secramento</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Jacksonville</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orlando</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Houston </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2five">
                    <div class="title last">
                        <p>Atlanta</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Jacksonville</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orlando</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Houston </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

My javascript code is given below.

```
$(".mainmenuitem .caret").on('click', function(event) {

})

$(".activeul").removeClass/addClass("main_nav_sub_show");
$(".caret").removeClass/addClass("caretrotate");
```

Here when user will click on span the class(i.e-`main_nav_sub_show` and `caretrotate`) will add inside that `li` element and removed from inside of other parent `li` element and vice versa. Please help.

Comment: Did you try toggleClass ?

Comment: yes but it could not as expected.

Comment: I just want to expand the current li and close rest li.

Comment: are you creating your own accordion component?

Comment: using that class its working but issue is to add/remove at proper click.

Answer (score 0):

For that I use this little code:

```
$(function(){
$('#YourID').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('TheClassToBeChanged').toggleClass('TheClassToBeChangedTo');
});
});
```

Assign the ID-attribute with "YourID" to the element that have to be changed e.g. a `<div>`. Upon click "TheClassToBeChanged" will change to "TheClassToBeChangedTo".

If you have more than one element of which you want to change class on simply copy/paste above script and assign them their own values.

```js
    $(function(){
    $('#YourID').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('TheClassToBeChanged').toggleClass('TheClassToBeChangedTo');
    });
    });
```

```css
.TheClassToBeChanged {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.TheClassToBeChangedTo {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="TheClassToBeChanged" id="YourID"></div>
```

You can assign a class to an element yet it clears all content inside the attribute. One solution could be to use above script and type in the classes that exist now and the classes that will exist after the click.

Another solution could be to wrap the element into a `<span>`, see snippet below.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.DontTryThisAtHome a', function(e) {
  $('.select a').unwrap()
  $(this).wrap("<span class='select'></span>");

});
```

```css
.DontTryThisAtHome {
  background: blue;
}

.select a {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DontTryThisAtHome">

  <p>
    <a href="#">Click</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">Click here</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">Click or here</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">But not here</a>
  </p>

</div>
```

---

**Expand/Collapse**

This can be done entirely by CSS where you don't need any JS/jQuery. [Please see how or an example on how here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972655/pure-css-several-read-more-read-less)

Comment: Here I need to add two class. Please check my post.

Comment: Here scenario is not like your posted answer and its like expand/collapse functinality.

Comment: That is what you create in your CSS with either `display: none;` or `height: 0;` and is another question. You ask on how to change classes on elements not how to create an expand/collapse function

Comment: How a look in my answer. I have added a link

Comment: Here I am adding/removing the class with other classes not changing any classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179620/discussion-between-subhra-and-simon-jensen).