# Convert jQuery which shows divs to plain JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote code which shows all the divs inside content in jQuery, but my boss doesn't want to load the jQuery library and wants to use only Javascript.

That's why I'm here. I will explain you my code

```js
$("#content_caract_1").hide();
$('#caract1').click(function() { // Au clic sur un élément
  $("#content_caract_1").toggle(400); // chache ou affiche a une vitesse constante (400)
});
$('#caract1bis').click(function() { // Au clic sur un élément
  $("#content_caract_1bis").toggle(400); // chache ou affiche a une vitesse constante (400)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="caract1">
  <h2> Etape 1 : Les enjeux et le parcours </h2>
</div>
<div id="content_caract_1">
  <div id="caract1bis">
    <h3> 1.1 Enjeux du programme apollo </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="content_caract_1bis">
    <p>
      <strong>BRAVO !</strong></br>
      </br>
      Vous êtes bien inscrit au parcours « excellence opérationnelle » qui se compose de 3 grandes étapes. Chacune de ces étapes à une durée de 1 à 2 mois.</br>
      </br>
      <strong>VOTRE DÉFI DE LA SEMAINE :</strong></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

The real problem is that I have about 20 divs to open and close. How can we do the same things in plain JS?

Comment: Try read this. Show/hide with CSS only. Easy enough to expand to 20 or more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972655/pure-css-several-read-more-read-less

Comment: But you have to give each parent div an index and duplicate the code for each index. This isn't different if you use CSS, jQuery or plain JS. It's all about finding the right language... IMHO use as little JS as you can.

Comment: Please note that you `</br>` tags make your HTML invalid, because it either has to be `<br />` (XML-conform) or `<br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the use of common classes instead of `id`'s and the use of `hide` class instead if direct style change.

**NOTE:** Just a side not `</br>` must be jsut `<br>`.

```js
var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  titles[i].addEventListener('click', toggleDisplay);
}

function toggleDisplay() {
  event.stopPropagation();

  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h2> Etape 1 : Les enjeux et le parcours </h2>
</div>
<div class="toggled_div hide">
  <div class="title">
    <h3> 1.1 Enjeux du programme apollo </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="toggled_div">
    <p>
      <strong>BRAVO !</strong>
      <br>
      <br> Vous êtes bien inscrit au parcours « excellence opérationnelle » qui se compose de 3 grandes étapes. Chacune de ces étapes à une durée de 1 à 2 mois.<br>
      <br>
      <strong>VOTRE DÉFI DE LA SEMAINE :</strong>
      <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="title">
  <h2> Etape 2 : Les enjeux et le parcours </h2>
</div>
<div class="toggled_div hide">
  <div class="title">
    <h3> 2.1 Enjeux du programme apollo </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="toggled_div">
    <p>
      <strong>BRAVO !</strong>
      <br>
      <br> Vous êtes bien inscrit au parcours « excellence opérationnelle » qui se compose de 3 grandes étapes. Chacune de ces étapes à une durée de 1 à 2 mois.<br>
      <br>
      <strong>VOTRE DÉFI DE LA SEMAINE :</strong>
      <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="title">
  <h2> Etape 3 : Les enjeux et le parcours </h2>
</div>
<div class="toggled_div hide">
  <div class="title">
    <h3> 3.1 Enjeux du programme apollo </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="toggled_div">
    <p>
      <strong>BRAVO !</strong>
      <br>
      <br> Vous êtes bien inscrit au parcours « excellence opérationnelle » qui se compose de 3 grandes étapes. Chacune de ces étapes à une durée de 1 à 2 mois.<br>
      <br>
      <strong>VOTRE DÉFI DE LA SEMAINE :</strong>
      <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this one @Nico

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for simple javascript

```js
 document.getElementById("content_caract_1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("caract1").onclick = function () {
    var carat1 = document.getElementById("content_caract_1");
    if (carat1.style.display === "none") {
        carat1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        carat1.style.display = "none";
    }
}
document.getElementById("caract1bis").onclick = function () {
    var carat_lbis = document.getElementById("content_caract_1bis");
    if (carat_lbis.style.display === "none") {
        carat_lbis.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        carat_lbis.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="caract1">
  <h2> Etape 1 : Les enjeux et le parcours </h2>
</div>
<div id="content_caract_1">
  <div id="caract1bis">
    <h3> 1.1 Enjeux du programme apollo </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="content_caract_1bis">
    <p>
      <strong>BRAVO !</strong></br></br>
      Vous êtes bien inscrit au parcours « excellence opérationnelle » qui se compose de 3 grandes étapes. Chacune de ces étapes à une durée de 1 à 2 mois.</br></br>
      <strong>VOTRE DÉFI DE LA SEMAINE :</strong></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't completely answer his question. How to achieve this for 20 blocks of text?

Comment: This is just to give him an idea to convert the code from js to simple javascript. I think he can add events to rest of the divs by himself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try to do something with that.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work for any number of `div` elements, as long as the HTML structure you've shown stay the same for all `div`s.

Step 1: Add a CSS class `.toggle` on the elements which you want to add as a visibility toggler.

Step 2: Initially set an inline style on any togglable elements that are supposed to be initially hidden.

Rest: see code.

```js
// get the toggle elements as an HTMLCollection and convert it to an array...
let togglers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('toggle'))

// so we can then use the array method .forEach() on it
togglers.forEach(function (toggler) {
  // for every element in our togglers collection, add a click listener
  toggler.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // check if element is visible
    let visible = this.nextElementSibling.style.display !== "none";
    // depending on the currrent visibility, apply either none or block
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = visible ? "none" : "block";
  })
})
```

```css
.toggle { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="caract1">
  <h2> Etape 1 : Les enjeux et le parcours </h2>
</div>
<div id="content_caract_1">
  <div id="caract1bis" class="toggle">
    <h3> 1.1 Enjeux du programme apollo </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="content_caract_1bis" style="display: none;">
    <p>
      <strong>BRAVO !</strong><br/>
      <br/>
      Vous êtes bien inscrit au parcours « excellence opérationnelle » qui se compose de 3 grandes étapes. Chacune de ces étapes à une durée de 1 à 2 mois.<br/>
      <br/>
      <strong>VOTRE DÉFI DE LA SEMAINE :</strong><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with pure JavaScript it will be more easy if you apply all XHTML standards to your html.

The first rule you didn't apply is your div id should be unique. You can get multiple elements by id with jQuery, but it's not apply in pure JavaScript. You should use class name to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="caract1">
    <h2> Etape 1 : Les enjeux et le parcours </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content_caract_1">
    <div class="caract1bis">
        <h3> 1.1 Enjeux du programme apollo </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content_caract_1bis">
        <p>
        <strong>BRAVO !</strong><br /><br />
        Vous êtes bien inscrit au parcours « excellence opérationnelle » qui se compose de 3 grandes étapes. Chacune de ces étapes à une durée de 1 à 2 mois.<br /><br />
        <strong>VOTRE DÉFI DE LA SEMAINE :</strong><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var divs = document.gelElementsByClassName('content_caract_1bis');
```

Also, because of XHTML standards you should use `<br />` not `</br>`